# What kind of changes should I start to see after three months of working out four times a week?

Tags: exercise, physique

Starting from near zero (i.e. I go to the gym and do cardio once a week or similar). But I want to eventually get fitter.

I'm thinking of doing Cardio two times a week and Strength building exercises two times a week.

I'm not overweight but I have a "pouch" in my stop which make my waistline bigger. At 26 I realize I need to be fitter. FYI I'm Male, 165.1 cm and weigh 62 kilograms.

In three months time, assuming I stick to my plans and cut out all junk food what kind of progress could I see in my physique?

Comment: This question needs way more details to be answerable. "I have a pouch", "doing cardio", "strength building exercises" aren't defined. A specific answer needs a specific question.

Comment: I think this question could reasonably be answered without more detail, by answering along the lines of "with a good resistance training program you could gain this amount of muscle or achieve this percentage increase in strength, or with a good running program you could expect to be able to run a half marathon in a reasonable time". So the answer gives the asker an indication of what is possible and how to assess whether his training is effective, rather than estimating the results that a specific program would give.